# dijit.TooltipDialog with pie chart

Tags: dojo, dialog, tooltip

Here I've created Pie Chart with MoveSlice. Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo: Monthly Sales Pie Chart with MoveSlice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../resources/style/demo.css" media="screen"-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pathToDojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <h1>Monthly Sales Pie Chart with MoveSlice</h1>

        <div id="chartNode" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></div>

        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script src="pathToDojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script>
        require([
             // Require the basic chart class
            "dojox/charting/Chart",

            // Require the theme of our choosing
            "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",

            // Charting plugins: 

            //  We want to plot a Pie chart
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",

            // Retrieve the Legend, Tooltip, and MoveSlice classes
            "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
            "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",


            //  We want to use Markers
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",

            //  We'll use default x/y axes
            "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",

            // Wait until the DOM is ready
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(Chart, theme, Pie, Tooltip, MoveSlice) {

            // Define the data
            var chartData = [10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288,12099];

            // Create the chart within it's "holding" node
            var chart = new Chart("chartNode");

            // Set the theme
            chart.setTheme(theme);

            // Add the only/default plot 
            chart.addPlot("default", {
                type: Pie,
                markers: true,
                radius:170
            });

            // Add axes
            chart.addAxis("x");
            chart.addAxis("y", { min: 5000, max: 30000, vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });

            // Add the series of data
            chart.addSeries("Monthly Sales - 2010",chartData);

            // Create the tooltip
            var tip = new Tooltip(chart,"default");

            // Create the slice mover
            var mag = new MoveSlice(chart,"default");

            // Render the chart!
            chart.render();


        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, MoveSlice moves a pie chart piece and Magnify slightly enlarges chart markers. When user takes mouse on particular pie, `Tooltip` appears with data defined with `var chartData = [10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288,12099];`. But here I want to use `TooltipDialog` instead of `Tooltip`. So that when user takes mouse on particular pie, that `TooltipDialog` should pop up.

Below is the code to create `TooltipDialog`. But I am not able to use it with Pie Chart.

```
require([
    "dijit/TooltipDialog",
    "dijit/popup",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(TooltipDialog, popup, on, dom){
    var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
        id: 'myTooltipDialog',
        style: "width: 300px;",
        content: "<p>I have a mouse leave event handler that will close the dialog.",
        onMouseLeave: function(){
            popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
        }
    });

    on(dom.byId('thenode'), 'mouseover', function(){
        popup.open({
            popup: myTooltipDialog,
            around: dom.byId('thenode')
        });
    });
});
```

How can I use `TooltipDialog` with Pie Chart?

Answer (score 0):

One not so easy solution is maybe to duplicate dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip code and replace any instanciation of a dijit/Tooltip by a dijit/TooltipDialog in your copy? Then use that modified action just as if you were using the regular one?